# Ajax запрос Node.js+Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Хочу отправить ajax запрос на сервер node.js.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
});
```

Событие error ничего не выдает, success выполняется. Вот серверная часть:

```
app.get('/', express.bodyParser(), function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

В консоль выводит пустые кавычки. Не могу понять в чем дело. Также использую шаблонизацию EJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. вы используете метод GET, данные отправляются через GET-параметры, чтобы получить к ним доступ нужно использовать `req.query`.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!